# Django 1.11: doesn't clean form field

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

everyone!
Implementing the edit/add functions to the app, I found that Django ignores my clean_<field_name> method in some classes. When I tried to debug it I found out that the methods are not even called. Here are the relevant code snippets:
**models.py**

```
class StoredItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["item"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}, {2} pcs.".format(self.item.serial, self.item.name, self.quantity)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('almacen:storeditem-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**forms.py**

```
# Stored items related forms
class NewOrEditStoredItemForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StoredItem.objects.all())
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    def clean_item(self):
        item = self.cleaned_data['item']
        storeds = map(lambda x: x.item, StoredItem.objects.all())
        if item in storeds:
            raise ValidationError(_("This item has already been stored - you only can change its quantity in the stock!"))

    def clean_quantity(self):
        quantity = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
        if quantity < 0:
            raise ValidationError(_("Items quantity can not be negative!"))
        return quantity
```

**views.py**

```
# Stored items related ---------------------------------------------------------------------
class CreateStoredItem(CreateView):
    model = StoredItem
    fields = '__all__'


class UpdateStoredItem(UpdateView):
    model = StoredItem
    fields = '__all__'
```

**storeditem_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base_template.html' %}

{% block header %}

    <h2 id="center">Stocked item add/delete </h2>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**
Resolved by rewriting the classes into functions. For classes I was recommended to use validators, but anyway, functions worked as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by rewriting the classes into functions. For classes I was recommended to use validators, but anyway, functions worked as I needed